# git skip a commit

Tags: git

Ok so I Have a branch  in git that looks like this

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

and a branch that looks like this

```
A-B-F-G
```

I want to make a branch like this

```
A-B-D-E-F-G
```

I think tagging might be involved but I am rather new to git.

Comment: Tagging has nothing to do with this, at all. Tagging lets you create symbolic names for commits.

Comment: That is a good explanation of tagging and it helps me understand. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to create a new branch, starting at commit `B`, and then cherry-pick the specific commits you're interested in onto your new branch.

```
git checkout my-branch <B-commit-id>

git cherry-pick <D-commit-id>
git cherry-pick <E-commit-id>
git cherry-pick <F-commit-id>
git cherry-pick <G-commit-id>
```

Comment: so cherry-pick adds on a single commit?(also git checkout my-branch is missing an n)

Comment: Yes, cherry-pick copies a single commit by its ID into your current branch.

Comment: @ellotheth They're disjoint, from different branches. You could at best use `D..E` and `F..G`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do a rebase on the other branch and an interactive rebase on commit B.

branchE points to Commit E. branchG points to Commit G

```
git checkout branchG
git rebase branchE
git rebase -i <B-commit-id>
```

Remove the complete line of C-Commit-Id. Save and close the editor. Finished.

Please read the help messages in the editor. It explains the possibilities of interactive rebase.